# Firestore Document with Object containing Reference

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage, google-cloud-firestore

I have really looked for this for a while now, but couldnt find what I need.
So I am using Firestore for my App and as you can see, I got an object in my database that contains a string and a reference.
I access the string like this:

```
String descriptionEx1 = (String) exI.get("description");
```

To access the image reference, I used:

```
StorageReference gsReference = (StorageReference) exI.get("image");
```

Then I thought Id download the image to a bitmap:

```
    final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
    storRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
            // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returns, use this as needed
            //ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgEx1);
            img = (int) ONE_MEGABYTE;
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
        }
    });
```

However, here I get an error (DocumentReference cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference) cause Im trying to cast a DocReference to a StorageReference.
But i need it to be storageRef to convert it into a bitmap...
Is there any other way to proceed?
Attached, a screenshot of my firestore database to clarify what i want to do.
Thanks for the help!

[image: Firestore Database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I went away from trying to use reference and converted the Reference in my database to a string with the url to the image as a value.
Then I simply queried this string object and used Glide and it works perfectly! :)
So I guess reference is not usable to refer to the storage, but maybe only to other documents?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not automatically converts the path you have to a `StorageReference`. Instead you'll have to create the `StorageReference` yourself and initialize it with the path from Firestore by calling [`FirebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(...)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FirebaseStorage.html#getReferenceFromUrl(java.lang.String)):

```
FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(exI.get("image"))
```

Comment: `StorageReference gsReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(exI.get("image"))` This, however tells me that it cannot be applied, cause the part in brackets is an object, not a string.. So i used `to.String()`, but then got this: **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The storage Uri could not be parsed.**